# Excel 2016: How to find a specific name in sheet "A" and and get the adjoining cell's value to a cell in sheet "B"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Excel 2016: How to find a specific name in sheet "ASPI" and and get the adjoining cell's value to a cell in sheet "Watchlist"?

I have currently used the method of this formula to get the cell value from one sheet to the other:  =ASPI!B80

But since the ASPI is dynamic with the data from the web, the Name of the company changes place when updated via the web.

So I thought that if there is a way for Excel to look up a specific name on ASPI and return the adjoining cell value to Watchlist, it should work.

I have added a link to sample file with just two entries for Watchlist here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fe1XQGDJWjEkIVgH6dTHAMHFX9xQmvTZ/view?usp=sharing

Will need to download and open in Excel as I don't think Google Drive shows the formula in the cell.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you'd want VLOOKUP

Comment: @towe  Thanks! Will look it up.